# How do I install newer versions (>3.26) of GNOME Files (aka Nautilus) on xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: xubuntu, nautilus

The default version of [GNOME Files](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Files) is 3.26, how can I install say, [3.34](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus/blob/mainline/NEWS) on Xubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Why? What's the use case? There are good reasons to stay with the version provided by your system's package manager.